# Windows XP Application Data Folder?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to access Windows XP's Application Data - but I'm having a slight issue, I am using the following code:

```
 Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

This is working correctly in any other opperating system - but Windows XP - On Windows XP it directs them to: `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data` - this is not the folder I want.

I want to access: `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data`

I have tried to do:

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\..\Local Settings\Application Data` - but I am getting .NET 'File Not Found' Errors.

What should I do? Please and Thank You!

Comment: When combining paths, always use [`System.IO.Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) regardless, because it will compensate for slashes and roots without complicated method calls: `IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "..\Local Settings\Application Data")` (Converted from 2011-11-29 answer.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you are looking for on XP is `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

Answer (score -1):

remove the `"\.."`  Try this:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\Local  Settings\Application Data
```

Comment: I want to go back a folder to get to the User's Folder - then to Local Settings\Application Data. There isn't a Local Settings folder inside Applications Folder. Because apparently there are two different Application Folders.

Comment: Ah sorry about that, I missed the Administrator user in the path :)  @Simon's solution looks to be the right one.