# How to get Application data folder?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i get the path of the current user’s “Application Data” folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915210/how-can-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-users-application-data-folder)
>   [Windows XP Application Data Folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305444/windows-xp-application-data-folder)

I have to save some settings in application data but, when i use something as `"@C:\Documents ..."` someone can run windous on D:\  So how to get that directory ??

Comment: And [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703281/getting-path-relative-to-the-current-working-directory) as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);` ...

And there's exaple, how you can use it:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

and it returns something like `C:\\Users\\UserName\\ApplicationData`

and you can use Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop too so you can get to desktop of actual user...

Answer (score 0):

see the code at the end of this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Look at this MSDN entry to get the application data directory, [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx).

What I used to do is use [Evironment.SystemDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.systemdirectory.aspx) and then break that down depending on what I need. But if you are worried about the drives then use the [DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx) class by doing `DriveInfo.GetDrives()`