# My FileSystemWatcher does not work c#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, filesystemwatcher

I have problem with FileSystemWatcher class. I Have this code:

```
RunningPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Reporter\\";
XMLConfigWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(RunningPath);
XMLConfigWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.Size;
XMLConfigWatcher.Filter = "database.xml";
XMLConfigWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(XMLConfigChanged);
XMLConfigWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

I want to observe one file - database.xml file. It it small file. I have win XP and it doesn't running on my computer, but my friend has Win 7 and it fires property. What's the reason and how to correct it?

And, of course, I attach Changed Event:

```
public void XMLConfigChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Config changed from outside.");
    foreach (ProgramToGrid f in collection)
    {
        f.watcher.finalize();
    }

    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
    {
        collection.Clear();
    });

    XmlAccess xml = XmlAccess.getInstance();

    foreach (Program f in xml.getApps())
    {
        ProgramToGrid ptg = new ProgramToGrid(f.getFolder(), f.getMail(), f.getSubject());
        ptg.watcher = new BugWatcher(f.getFolder(), f.getMail(), f.getSubject());

        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            collection.Add(ptg);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be related to this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305444/windows-xp-application-data-folder

Comment: Hi! I don't think so, due to the Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData is valid for me. I printed it, and it is correct path.

Comment: what do you mean you printed it?  try if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(RunningPath))

Comment: I write this:            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(RunningPath)) { 
            
                MessageBox.Show(RunningPath);
            
            } And it show a message with correct path

Comment: I also confirm - FileSystemWatcher seems does not work at all! :-(
So, I have to use BackgroundWorker and FileInfo classes to explicitly compare file parameters to see if there was any changes.
I think there is wrong code sample in MS site for FileSystemWatcher.